# Pushing to Github from Free Heroku Dyno

Tags: github, heroku, ssh

I'm looking to push data from a heroku server to my github repo daily. I want to follow best practice by using an SSH key to commit to my repo. But not experienced enough working with heroku...

1. Is it possible to SSH into the heroku dyno and setup the SSH key?
2. If not... would it make sense to create the SSH key pair on my computer and then either (a) copy the private key into the heroku server or (b) include the private key as an environment variable on my heroku project (might be a very long text string)?

Alternatively, how unsecure would it be to include my email and password in the heroku environment variables and push to github via HTTPS?

Overall, just looking for some guidance as there's no information I could find online on how to do this specifically on Heroku using the free plan